# Assigning question to product owners from salesforce

Tags: discussion

I read this question here : [How can we get "Developer" bugs logged with Technical Support?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14818/how-can-we-get-developer-bugs-logged-with-technical-support)

I see a lot of Salesforce folks come and comment in this community randomly every now and then. If not to everyone, if the product owners let themselves know to our moderators, the moderators can assign the issue for the internal folks review.

Once an issue is potentially identified as bug(maybe flag it for moderators attention or tag is as a platform bug), it would be awesome if some one from salesforce acts like a point of contact who can connect with a program manager for the feature and get some answer/comment about the question and the moderators can post the product manager feedback. I know this is too much work on moderators, other alternative effective approach will work too.

Working with Lightning I see so many bugs that may have workarounds that are known only to a few users. From the inception of this community I have found many valuable answers here, I am not too active on twitter and I report issues every now and then when I find one. With an awesome community like this twitter seems tedious option to choose and search for issues.

If the community thinks this to be a duplicate question (or) meta topic, I will move/delete it without a second thought.

Comment: Great idea, I was wondering about the same thing a couple times!